# Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with float

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following SQL statement:

```
select pc.*,au.UserName from ProspectsInCampaigns pc 
inner join prospects p on p.id=pc.prospectid 
inner join aspnet_Users au on STR(au.UserId)=pc.updatedby
WHERE p.id=1225982
```

The problem is, that the updatedby field in ProspectsInCampaigns contains either an empty string, or a string that is indeed a UUID.
In the above case I get the error:

> Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier
>   is incompatible with float

How can I prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't compare the `UUID` to a `float`.  Why are you doing that anyways?

[You can consult this handy chart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) to know what conversions are allowed.  If you can't convert two datatypes to each other, you can't compare them directly.

Hypothetically you could convert both to a string type like `varchar` but since it's impossible to have a `UUID` match anything that can be a `float` there's no point.

**Edit:**

More specifically, it looks like `Userid` is a `UUID` and the `STR()` function is specifically for converting `float` data to a string datatype.

Why are you trying to convert au.UserID anyway? If you have a UUID, compare it to the other UUID directly.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying for me, Ken.